# Call SOAP service in Yii framework

Tags: php, soap, yii

I am trying to call SOAP service in my Yii (1.1) project.

```
$client=new SoapClient('https://secure.idxre.com/ihws/subscriberwebservice.cfc');
echo $client->getSubscriber($uid,$sid,$email);
```

This code is giving me following error:

**Error 500**

SoapClient::SoapClient(https://secure.idxre.com/ihws/subscriberwebservice.cfc): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

I am not able to find out the issue. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to this article http://support.ihomefinder.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/124/0/subscriber-web-service you should enable wsdl mode. Add `?wsdl` to your query. It's output right XML for me.

Comment: @SiZE: Worked...:) Add it as answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this article http://support.ihomefinder.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/124/0/subscriber-web-service you should enable wsdl mode. Add `?wsdl` to your query. It's output right XML for me.

Comment: it is working as i changed the request to $client=new SoapClient('https://secure.idxre.com/ihws/subscriberwebservice.cfc?wsdl');